# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Swap Texture Fails

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have searched quite a bit and all the similar problems and solutions have not worked for me yet. So I hope someone will recognize my problem

Problem Description: 
What I want to do is to swap with which texture I am rendering with.
When the application starts I load a texture and it renders fine. 
Later I want to replace it and calls the same load function again thus generating a new texture id. When I render with the new texture id I encounter the problem of the model becoming completely black.

So if I run the code below the above happens:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), 
    R.drawable.sphere_map1);
currentTexture = TextureHelper.loadTextureToOGL(bmp);
```

I get the problem with a completely black texture.

Here follow some of the important functions that I use to load a texture and draw my model
If anyone need additional code, let me know. As this is my first post feel free to do recommendations regarding the structure of the post as well.

Thanks on beforehand!

```
 public static int loadTextureToOGL(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int texId[] = { -1 };
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texId, 0);
    int textureId = texId[0];
    glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, mMinFilter);
    glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, mMaxFilter);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, GL_RGBA, bitmap, 0);
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    GeneralUtil.printGLErrorInHex();
    bitmap.recycle();

    return textureId;
}

public void draw(float[] mvp) {
    glUseProgram(mProgram);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordHandle);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, currentTexture);
    glUniform1i(mEnvTex0Handle, 0);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPHandle, 1, false, mvp, 0);

    glUniform3f(mColorHandle, red, green, blue);
    glUniform1f(mAttSpecularHandle, attSpecular);
    glUniform1f(mAttDiffuseHandle, attDiffuse);
    glUniform1f(mAttAmbientHandle, attAmbient);

    GeneralUtil.printGLErrorInHex();
    if (model != null) {
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getmNFaces() * 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it make any chance if you remove internal format from ``GLUtils.texImage2D(...)`` and let GLUtils determine it automatically?

Comment: Actually that is how I had it first, so that made no difference :(

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. At first you say *if I **re**load a texture, it fails*, and then you say *If I run this, it fails*, with a snippet that doesn't show any reloading at all. If it really only fails the second time, can you show the whole context, showing the first load, and the second failing load, and how you draw it?

Comment: I agree it was a bit fuzzy. The situation is hard to explain good in word, but I rewrote it to emphasize on what I want happening and what actually happens. I hope it is more clear. So reloading is bad wording. I rather want to replace the texture I am rendering with, with another texture.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found my problem.

Instead of running the glTexImage call from the GL thread I ran it from the UI thread instead.
I did not realize that it created a GL thread on its own.